# Можете объяснить почему bootstrap не ставит блоки в строчку и как сделать, что бы он ставил блоки в строчку

Tags: веб-программирование, вёрстка, bootstrap

```css
.portfolio__text h2{
 font-size: 40px;
 font-weight: bold;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 }

.portfolio__text p{
 font-size: 18px;
 color: #777777;
 font-family: serif;
}

.portfolio__text{
 text-align: center;
 margin: 0 auto;
 padding-bottom: 80px;
  }
.portfolio{
 padding-top: 120px;
 background: $background;
 }
.portfolio-block{
 background: #fff;
 max-width: 290px;
 max-height: 410px;
 padding: 0;
 }
.portfolio-block__text{
 text-align: center;
 padding-bottom: 5px;
 padding-top: 30px;
}
img {
max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Golden</title>
 <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
</head>
<body>
<section class="portfolio">
  <div class="container">
   <div class="row">
    <div class="portfolio__text col-lg-12">
     <h2>Our portfolio</h2>
     <i><p>Proin iaculis purus consequat sem cure. </p></i>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="row">
    <div class="portfolio-blocks">
      <div class="portfolio-block ebony-ivory col-lg-3 offset-lg-0">
       <div class="image">
       <img src="http://cdn.iz.ru/sites/default/files/styles/900x506/public/news-2018-05/Depositphotos_37289893_l-2015.jpg?itok=6qX1E6gM" alt="">
       </div>
       <div class="portfolio-block__text">
        <h4>Ebony & Ivory</h4>
        <i><p>Branding</p></i>
       </div>

      </div>
      <div class="portfolio-block ebony-ivory col-lg-3">
       <div class="image">
       <img src="http://cdn.iz.ru/sites/default/files/styles/900x506/public/news-2018-05/Depositphotos_37289893_l-2015.jpg?itok=6qX1E6gM" alt="">
       </div>
       <div class="portfolio-block__text">
        <h4>Ebony & Ivory</h4>
        <i><p>Branding</p></i>
       </div>
      </div>
      <div class="portfolio-block ebony-ivory col-lg-3">
       <div class="image">
       <img src="http://cdn.iz.ru/sites/default/files/styles/900x506/public/news-2018-05/Depositphotos_37289893_l-2015.jpg?itok=6qX1E6gM" alt="">
       </div>
       <div class="portfolio-block__text">
        <h4>Ebony & Ivory</h4>
        <i><p>Branding</p></i>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
 </section>
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Неправильная структура у вас `.row --> .portfolio-blocks --> [class*=col-]`

Необходимо так - `.row --> [class*=col-]`

```css
.portfolio__text h2 {
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.portfolio__text p {
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #777777;
  font-family: serif;
}

.portfolio__text {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-bottom: 80px;
}

.portfolio {
  padding-top: 120px;
  background: $background;
}

.portfolio-block {
  background: #fff;
  max-width: 290px;
  max-height: 410px;
  padding: 0;
}

.portfolio-block__text {
  text-align: center;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  padding-top: 30px;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Golden</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
</head>

<body>
  <section class="portfolio">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="portfolio__text col-lg-12">
          <h2>Our portfolio</h2>
          <i><p>Proin iaculis purus consequat sem cure. </p></i>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row portfolio-blocks">

        <div class="portfolio-block ebony-ivory col-lg-3 offset-lg-0">
          <div class="image">
            <img src="http://cdn.iz.ru/sites/default/files/styles/900x506/public/news-2018-05/Depositphotos_37289893_l-2015.jpg?itok=6qX1E6gM" alt="">
          </div>
          <div class="portfolio-block__text">
            <h4>Ebony & Ivory</h4>
            <i><p>Branding</p></i>
          </div>

        </div>
        <div class="portfolio-block ebony-ivory col-lg-3">
          <div class="image">
            <img src="http://cdn.iz.ru/sites/default/files/styles/900x506/public/news-2018-05/Depositphotos_37289893_l-2015.jpg?itok=6qX1E6gM" alt="">
          </div>
          <div class="portfolio-block__text">
            <h4>Ebony & Ivory</h4>
            <i><p>Branding</p></i>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="portfolio-block ebony-ivory col-lg-3">
          <div class="image">
            <img src="http://cdn.iz.ru/sites/default/files/styles/900x506/public/news-2018-05/Depositphotos_37289893_l-2015.jpg?itok=6qX1E6gM" alt="">
          </div>
          <div class="portfolio-block__text">
            <h4>Ebony & Ivory</h4>
            <i><p>Branding</p></i>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```